# How to implement Paypal payouts with paypal smart button integration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have implemented PayPal checkout API in my rails application by using the [SmartButtons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/) and by creating the order in the [server-side](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

I have used the [payouts-ruby-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-Ruby-SDK) gem and my code is as follows:-

```
index.html.erb
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xyz&currency=USD"></script>

<script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Call your server to set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/orders', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                return orderData.orderID;
            });
        },

        // Call your server to finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/orders/' + data.orderID + '/capture', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(orderData) {
                // Three cases to handle:
                //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show a success / thank you message

                // Your server defines the structure of 'orderData', which may differ
                var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];

                if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                    // Recoverable state, see: "Handle Funding Failures"
                    // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                    return actions.restart();
                }

                if (errorDetail) {
                    var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                    if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                    if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                    // Show a failure message
                    return alert(msg);
                }

                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
  end

  def create
    # Creating Access Token for Sandbox
        client_id =  'xyz'
      client_secret = 'abc'
        # Creating an environment
        environment = PayPal::SandboxEnvironment.new(client_id, client_secret)
        client = PayPal::PayPalHttpClient.new(environment)

        request = PayPalCheckoutSdk::Orders::OrdersCreateRequest::new
        request.request_body({
                                intent: "CAPTURE",
                                purchase_units: [
                                    {
                                        amount: {
                                            currency_code: "USD",
                                            value: "10.00"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                              })

        begin
        # Call API with your client and get a response for your call
        # debugger
        response = client.execute(request)
        puts response.result.id
        render json: {success: true, orderID: response.result.id}
        rescue PayPalHttp::HttpError => ioe
            # Something went wrong server-side
            puts ioe.status_code
            puts ioe.headers["debug_id"]
        end
  end

  def execute_payment
    client_id =  'xyz'
    client_secret = 'abc'
        # Creating an environment
        environment = PayPal::SandboxEnvironment.new(client_id, client_secret)
        client = PayPal::PayPalHttpClient.new(environment)

      request = PayPalCheckoutSdk::Orders::OrdersCaptureRequest::new(session[:orderID])

        begin
            # Call API with your client and get a response for your call
            response = client.execute(request) 
            
            # If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
            order = response.result
            puts order
        rescue PayPalHttp::HttpError => ioe
            # Something went wrong server-side
            puts ioe.status_code
            puts ioe.headers["debug_id"]
        end
  end
end
```

Now I want to implement the Paypal's Payouts API and I know that [paypal-ruby-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-Ruby-SDK) is available for it but I am confused where to fit this code and how to integrate it with the front end. Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is Checkout code, for both front-end (JavaScript), and back-end (Ruby).

Payouts has nothing to do with Checkout, neither front-end Checkout nor back-end Checkout.

Payouts is strictly a backend API operation, where you send money from your account to another account.

Payouts does not connect to any front-end UI. You can build your own UI to trigger a payout, if you need one. Presumably you know who you want to send money from your account to, and what process should trigger this action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Here I have a portal where a user can buy a course and I have to transfer the money to the course owner and a 10% commission to the admin what should I implement in this case?

Comment: Who is the person with Payouts enabled on their account? The admin? If they pay 100% to the admin, then the admin could later send a payout for 90% to the owner.

Comment: Admin is the person with payouts enabled and yes i have used the checkout to pay the 100% to the admin and admin will send the 90% to the course owner using the payouts. Is it the right way?